# How to create an object like wave

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, path-effects

I need to create an object like this

[image: Picture 1]

If I use Pencil tool I get something like this

[image: Picture 2]

As you can see wave parts are not equal. I can try harder with Pencil tool to create a perfect wave but it will take much time.

When applying a ZigZag filter on the rectangle an excellent wave object is created but the wave is the part of the whole object.

[image: Picture 3]

Is there any way to cut part of the rectangle object to get an object like on the picture 1 ? Or maybe there is a simpler way to create the object like on the picture 1?

Comment: Object -> Expand Appearance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Start with a horizontal path and apply a **Zig Zag** Effect

[image]

- Menu **Object** > **Expand Appearance**
- Delete the side points
- Select the side points and click the **Convert to Corner** icon

[image: Convert to corner]

- Move them down and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> Win to join the points
- Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> Win to see the scale box and holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> scale the points to the center

[image: waves]

Answer (score 3):

In the future you maybe really need cutting in Illustrator. You can use Clipping Masks (this is non-destructive),  Pathfinder panel operations or you can use Object > Path > Divide Objects Below.

Only one example. It's of the Pathfinder panel:

Step 1: Fix the effect on your zigzagged rectangle. Select it and goto Object > Expand Appearance which returns identical shape, but it's a path without effects.

Step 2: Draw a rectangle or other cosed path over the shape to be clipped. Select both.

Step 3: Apply Pathfinder panel operation Intersect. It removes the extras.

See steps 2 and 3 in the next image:

[image]

You may want to fine tune the shape. It's possible with anchor point editing tools ie. the direct selection tool and what's hidden under the Pen in the toolbox. Here the corners are reshaped:

[image]

Anchor point editing is the very basic part of using Illustrator efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

You could try drawing it manually, by using the Pen Tool, and enabling the Grid, and Snap to Grid.

[image]